# How can I find wifi speed in Android and how can I display wifi speed in TextView?

Tags: java, android

To find wifi speed I used this code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
if (wifiInfo != null) {
    int linkSpeed = wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed(); //measured using WifiInfo.LINK_SPEED_UNITS
    //txtSpeed.setText(linkSpeed);
}
```

I want to display the speed in my TextView. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This ::**

```
TextView speedcount;

    String s = Integer.toString(linkSpeed);
    speedcount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    speedcount.setText(s);
```

Comment: what ever code i wrote for to get speed of wifi is it correct?

Comment: 12-21 18:44:41.270: E/AndroidRuntime(492):  at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.getConnectionInfo(WifiManager.java:675)
12-21 18:44:41.270: E/AndroidRuntime(492):  at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.getConnectionInfo(IWifiManager.java:686)

Answer (score 0):

`txtSpeed.setText(""+linkSpeed);` or `textSpeed.setText(Integer.toString(linkSpeed));`. Make sure `txtSpeed` is instantiated properly.